# Do maps of the form $A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B$ have a name?

Tags: operator-theory, terminology, tensor-products

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are operators on two different Hilbert spaces and consider the operator
$A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B$ on the tensor product of the two Hilbert spaces. Does this property have a special name?

Comment: Kronecker sum $A\oplus B$?

Comment: I mean tensor product.